# Java doesn't have information about all IANA time zones

Tags: java, timezone, java-time, timezone-offset

I'm trying to map the values that come from the Front-End to `ZoneId` class like this:

```
Optional.ofNullable(timeZone).map(ZoneId::of).orElse(null)
```

For most time zones it works fine, however, for some values Java throws exception:

```
java.time.zone.ZoneRulesException: Unknown time-zone ID: America/Punta_Arenas
```

However, it is a valid time-zone according to IANA:
https://www.iana.org/time-zones

> Zone America/Punta_Arenas -4:43:40 -  LMT 1890

I was thinking about using offset for such time-zones (just to hardcode values), but I guess there should be more convenient way to solve the issue. Is there a way Java can handle that?

Other timezones that are not supported:

- America/Punta_Arenas
- Asia/Atyrau
- Asia/Famagusta
- Asia/Yangon
- EST
- Europe/Saratov
- HST
- MST
- ROC

My Java version: "1.8.0_121" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

Comment: Which version of Java are you using exactly; the latest update of Java 8? Time zone information is updated frequently with new Java updates, it's possible that you are using a specific Java version in which the one you are referencing is not defined.

Comment: I tried it out with Java 8 update 144 (currently the latest version) and it works as expected.

Comment: java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

Comment: Then update to the latest version.

Comment: Is that OK to rely on Java version to parse time zones? What if prod servers uses different versions and update it there is rather difficult. They should have provided a more reliable way...

Comment: The 3-letter names (like EST or HST) are not supported by `ZoneId`, mainly because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231) - although you can use the [`SHORT_IDS` map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#SHORT_IDS), which has some default/retro-compatible/controversial mappings

Comment: You can update timezone data regardless of Java version: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html

Comment: @Hugo, thanks, I like that way. It's more convenient than updating whole java.  SHORT_IDS - good idea!

Comment: You can also use your own map of IDs if you want, and use it in the [`of(name, map)` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#of-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-)

Comment: @Hugo, thanks! What's about writing an answer to summarize all of this ? :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've tested with Java 1.8.0_121 and some zones are really missing.

The most obvious way to fix it is to update Java's version - in Java 1.8.0_131 all the zones above are available - except the 3-letter names (`EST`, `HST`, etc), more on that below.

But I know that updates in production environments are not as easy (nor fast) as we'd like. In this case, you could use the [TZUpdater tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html), which can update JDK's timezone data without changing Java's version.

---

The only detail is that `ZoneId` doesn't work with the 3-letter abbreviations (`EST`, `HST` and so on). That's because those names are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231).

If you want to use them, though, you can use a map of custom ID's. `ZoneId` comes with a built-in map:

```
ZoneId.of("EST", ZoneId.SHORT_IDS);
```

The problem is that the [choices used in the `SHORT_IDS` map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#SHORT_IDS) are - like any other choice - arbitrary and even controversial. If you want to use different zones for each abbreviation, just create your own map:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("EST", "America/New_York");
... put how many names you want
System.out.println(ZoneId.of("EST", map)); // creates America/New_York
```

The only exceptions for 3-letter names are, of course, **GMT** and **UTC**, but in this case it's better to just use the `ZoneOffset.UTC` constant.

---

If you can't update your Java version nor run the TZUpdater tool, there's another (much more difficult) alternative.

You can extend the `java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider` class and make a provider that can create the missing ID's. Something like that:

```
public class MissingZonesProvider extends ZoneRulesProvider {

    private Set<String> missingIds = new HashSet<>();

    public MissingZonesProvider() {
        missingIds.add("America/Punta_Arenas");
        missingIds.add("Europe/Saratov");
        // add all others
    }

    @Override
    protected Set<String> provideZoneIds() {
        return this.missingIds;
    }

    @Override
    protected ZoneRules provideRules(String zoneId, boolean forCaching) {
        ZoneRules rules = null;
        if ("America/Punta_Arenas".equals(zoneId)) {
            rules = // create rules for America/Punta_Arenas
        }
        if ("Europe/Saratov".equals(zoneId)) {
            rules = // create rules for Europe/Saratov
        }
        // and so on

        return rules;
    }

    // returns a map with the ZoneRules, check javadoc for more details
    @Override
    protected NavigableMap<String, ZoneRules> provideVersions(String zoneId) {
        TreeMap<String, ZoneRules> map = new TreeMap<>();
        ZoneRules rules = provideRules(zoneId, false);
        if (rules != null) {
            map.put(zoneId, rules);
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

Create the `ZoneRules` is most the complicated part.

One way is to get the latest [IANA files](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) and read them. You can take a look at [JDK source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/time/zone/TzdbZoneRulesProvider.java#TzdbZoneRulesProvider.load%28java.io.DataInputStream%29) to see how it creates `ZoneRules` from that (although I'm not sure if the file that's inside JDK is in the exact same format as IANA's files).

Anyway, [this link](ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/tz-how-to.html) explains how to read IANA's files. Then you can take a look at [`ZoneRules` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html) to know how to map IANA information to Java classes. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44419074/7605325) I create a very simple `ZoneRules` with just 2 transition rules, so you can get a basic idea of how to do it.

Then you need to register the provider:

```
ZoneRulesProvider.registerProvider(new MissingZonesProvider());
```

And now the new zones will be available:

```
ZoneId.of("America/Punta_Arenas");
ZoneId.of("Europe/Saratov");
... and any other you added in the MissingZonesProvider class
```

There are other ways to use the provider (instead of registering), [check the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRulesProvider.html) for more details. In the same javadoc there are also more details about how to properly implement a zone rules provider (my version above is very simple and probably it's missing some details, like the implementation of `provideVersions` - it should use the provider's version as a key, not the zone ID as I'm doing, etc).

Of course this provider must be discarded as soon as you update the Java version (because you can't have 2 providers that create zones with the same ID: if the new provider creates an ID that already exists, it throws an exception when you try to register it).