# Custom ZoneIds / Time Zones in Java

Tags: java, time, timezone, icalendar

I'm attempting to model an iCalendar `VTIMEZONE` object using Java's `ZoneId` and `ZoneOffsetTransitionRule`.

My `VTIMEZONE` object looks like

```
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Central European Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16010101T030000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010101T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTH=1;BYDAY=MO
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
```

I need to create my own `ZoneId` to model this because, as far as I know, there isn't a `ZoneId` available with these offsets and in which DST starts on the first Monday of January (as opposed to some Sunday of March).

I have the following for creating a `ZoneOffsetTransitionRule`

```
ZoneOffsetTransitionRule of =
  ZoneOffsetTransitionRule.of(Month.JANUARY, 1, DayOfWeek.MONDAY, LocalTime.of(2, 0),
    false, ZoneOffsetTransitionRule.TimeDefinition.STANDARD, ZoneOffset.ofHours(1),
    ZoneOffset.ofHours(1), ZoneOffset.ofHours(2));
```

But I'm not sure if it's correct or how to create a `ZoneId` from this.

- Is that transition rule accurate to model the `DAYLIGHT` component of my `VTIMEZONE`?
- How can I create a `ZoneId` from this so I can eventually create a `ZonedDateTime`?

Comment: No matter what you get in your iCalendar, I don’t think such a time zone exists in reality.

Comment: You may see if you can implement and register a [`ZoneRulesProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRulesProvider.html).

Comment: @OleV.V.: How can I get a `ZoneId` from `ZoneRulesProvider`?

Comment: There’s an example at the bottom of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44397874/getting-zoneid-from-a-simpletimezone/44419074#44419074). As I read the documentation, you will have to invent a unique name for your new `ZoneId`.

Answer (score 8):

The only way to get a `ZoneId` (at least if we’re not *very* hacky) is through the factory methods of `ZoneId` and its subclass `ZoneOffset`. It might seem at first that this leaves of with the built-in `ZoneId`s. However, there’s a backdoor for specifying additional `ZoneId`s that `ZoneId.of` can then produce. It’s called `ZoneRulesProvider`. We need to specify an new and unique ID and we need to specify the zone rules (hence the name `ZoneRulesProvider`).

So with your `ZoneOffsetTransitionRule` you are already on the way. We need two of them, though, yours for transitioning to DST (which would normally have happened in the spring) and one for going the other way in the fall.

The following listing isn’t production code, of course, but is just to demonstrate that it is doable to develop and register your own `ZoneRulesProvider`.

```
    final String customZoneId = "Custom-CEST-1";

    final ZoneOffset standardOffset = ZoneOffset.ofHours(1);
    final ZoneOffset summerTimeOffset = ZoneOffset.ofHours(2);
    // At least one transistion is required
    ZoneOffsetTransition initialTransition = ZoneOffsetTransition.of(
            LocalDateTime.of(1601, 1, 1, 3, 0), summerTimeOffset, standardOffset);
    List<ZoneOffsetTransition> transitionList = List.of(initialTransition);

    // Rules for going to and from summer time (DST)
    ZoneOffsetTransitionRule springRule =
            ZoneOffsetTransitionRule.of(Month.JANUARY, 1, DayOfWeek.MONDAY, LocalTime.of(2, 0),
                    false, ZoneOffsetTransitionRule.TimeDefinition.STANDARD, standardOffset,
                    standardOffset, summerTimeOffset);
    ZoneOffsetTransitionRule fallRule =
            ZoneOffsetTransitionRule.of(Month.OCTOBER, -1, DayOfWeek.SUNDAY, LocalTime.of(2, 0),
                    false, ZoneOffsetTransitionRule.TimeDefinition.STANDARD, standardOffset,
                    summerTimeOffset, standardOffset);
    ZoneRules rules = ZoneRules.of(standardOffset, standardOffset,
            transitionList, transitionList, List.of(springRule, fallRule));

    // The heart of the magic: the ZoneRulesProvider
    ZoneRulesProvider customProvider = new ZoneRulesProvider() {

        @Override
        protected Set<String> provideZoneIds() {
            return Set.of(customZoneId);
        }

        @Override
        protected NavigableMap<String, ZoneRules> provideVersions(String zoneId) {
            return new TreeMap<>(Map.of(customZoneId, rules));
        }

        @Override
        protected ZoneRules provideRules(String zoneId, boolean forCaching) {
            return rules;
        }
    };

    // Registering the ZoneRulesProvider is the key to ZoneId using it
    ZoneRulesProvider.registerProvider(customProvider);

    // Get an instance of our custom ZoneId
    ZoneId customZone = ZoneId.of(customZoneId);
    // Transition to standard time was Sunday, October 29, 2017,
    // so try the day before and the day after
    System.out.println(LocalDate.of(2017, Month.OCTOBER, 28).atStartOfDay(customZone));
    System.out.println(LocalDate.of(2017, Month.OCTOBER, 30).atStartOfDay(customZone));
    // The special thing about our custom ZoneID is that transition to DST
    // happened on Monday, January 1. Try the day before and the day after.
    System.out.println(LocalDate.of(2017, Month.DECEMBER, 31).atStartOfDay(customZone));
    System.out.println(LocalDate.of(2018, Month.JANUARY, 2).atStartOfDay(customZone));
```

The code prints:

```
2017-10-28T00:00+02:00[Custom-CEST-1]
2017-10-30T00:00+01:00[Custom-CEST-1]
2017-12-31T00:00+01:00[Custom-CEST-1]
2018-01-02T00:00+02:00[Custom-CEST-1]
```

We see that we get the expected DST offset of +02:00 exactly before the transition to standard time and again after the transition to summer time.